# Coproducts in Lean

Tags: lean

All,

I am using Lean. I am hoping to obtain a coproduct construction which works something like this:

```
A : Type
B : Type
COPRODUCT(A, B) : Type
a : A \rightarrow C
b : B \rightarrow C
COPROD(a, b) : COPRODUCT(A, B) \rightarrow C
FIRST : A \rightarrow COPRODUCT(A, B)
SECOND : B \rightarrow COPRODUCT(A, B)
t : COPRODUCT(A, B) \rightarrow C
t \circ FIRST = a
t \circ SECOND = b
```

Is the easiest way here to use dependent sum over Bool?

Note that this follows pretty literally the universal property for coproduct, which is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/core.html#sum

Comment: COPRODUCT(a, b) is https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/data/sum/basic.html#sum.elim , FIRST is https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/core.html#sum.inl , SECOND is sum.inr, and the last two lines are https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/data/sum/basic.html#sum.elim_inl and sum.elim_inr.

Comment: Also see this section of the tutorial on coproducts and similar types: https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/inductive_types.html#constructors-with-arguments

Comment: Also see section 1.7 of the [HoTT book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) if you want more detail.  But in essence, in Lean (and DTT in general) types like `sum` have a corresponding `sum.rec` eliminator, and this is what all other properties including the universal properties are derivable from.

Comment: @JunyanXu I think that is enough to make an answer. Would you mind doing that?

Comment: @Trebor ___ Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a bit more commentary to Junyan Xu's answer, yes the built in `sum` is the  right way to go with coproducts, but of course for some applications you just want to make your own new `coproduct` type or a variation there of.  With Lean this is trivial using inductive types.  (This is Lean 3 syntax, but with Lean 4 it is similar.)

```
inductive coproduct (A B : Type*)
| first : A -> coproduct
| second : B -> coproduct

-- type type constructors are automatically created
#print coproduct.first  -- constructor coproduct.first : Π {A : Type u_1} {B : Type u_2}, A → coproduct A B
#print coproduct.second -- constructor coproduct.second : Π {A : Type u_1} {B : Type u_2}, B → coproduct A B

def coprod {A B C : Type*} (f : A -> C) (g : B -> C) : coproduct A B -> C
| (coproduct.first a)  := f a
| (coproduct.second b) := g b
```

Note, you will almost never need to use the `coprod` function directly, and I would greatly caution against doing so except in special circumstances.  Instead the notation I used to prove `coprod` is quite general and easy to use.  It matches similar `match` notation used in other functional programming languages.  Here are two more examples using both the notation for recursive functions and `match` notation:

```
-- this is a recursive function
def coproduct_swap {A B : Type*} : coproduct A B -> coproduct B A
| (coproduct.first a)  := coproduct.second a
| (coproduct.second b) := coproduct.first b

def coproduct_and_function {A B : Type*} (cop : coproduct A B) (f : A -> B) : B :=
-- this example uses match notation
match cop with
| (coproduct.first a)  := f a
| (coproduct.second b) := b
end
```

---

Given your many questions so far on basic points of the syntax and logic, I would highly recommend that your read and work through the examples in the tutorial "Theorem Proving in Lean" ([Lean 3 version](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/), [Lean 4 version](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/tpil.html)).  I think it would help you a lot with all of your questions.  But if you still have follow up questions, feel free to ask them here or on the Lean Zulip.

Answer (score 4):

- `COPRODUCT(A, B)` is [`sum`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/core.html#sum)
- `COPROD(a, b)` is [`sum.elim`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/data/sum/basic.html#sum.elim)
- `FIRST` is `sum.inl`
- `SECOND` is `sum.inr`
- `COPROD(a, b) \circ FIRST = a` and
  `COPROD(a, b) \circ SECOND = b` are
  [`sum.elim_inl`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/data/sum/basic.html#sum.elim_inl)
  and `sum.elim_inr`.